# how to build e-commerce shopping site software?

Tags: e-commerce

I've a plan to build a e-commerce shopping site software. Let anyone who wants a e-commerce site, he will sign up on my site e-commerce shopping site software, then a store will be created for him with subdomain, if my e-commerce site is e-commerce.com, he signed up with store name "sample", now he will have a store like sample.e-commerce.com.  He can also point his domain to this store, with separate admin access for that site - can update the configuration for him(theme, discount, product bundle, select payment gateway etc), can start to sell. I prefer to build this site using php. See the following similar sites -

shopify, vendr, foxycart, bigcommerce, volusion, bigcartel, corecommerce etc

i prefer to build my site using php, what should be the architecture? how i should start build? Is there any existing tool? Is there any existing tool in other languages(ruby, python)

Thanks

Comment: [oscommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/)

Comment: read it carefully again. thanks

Comment: @phwd's comment seems like a valid solution and we're trying to help you - no need to be rude about it. If you have a specific objection to his suggestion, please explain it. It's already a VAST question with a lot of issues to overcome. The fact that you don't know how to start suggests you're unlikely to be able to complete this project with your current skill level - and payment handling is a bad one to get wrong.

Comment: [OpenCart](https://www.opencart.com/) has some multi-tenant capabilities - it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Magento (http://www.magentocommerce.com/): it is an open-source CMS create specifically to easily create e-commerce sites. It ships with a multi-store functionality... 
and it has many additional interesting features, like SEO optimization procedures, etc.

You could start installing that, testing it on your local system and eventually adapting it according to your needs. I think it is a great tool and it can save you a great deal of work.

Magento is written in PHP.

Cheers,
Gianluca.

Comment: Thanks Gianluca, I know about Magento for its multi store support but does this support for separate admin(for each store) and what about different theme implementation from admin? What about cloud hosting and distributed database stuff? Would you explain more these stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. I suggesting reading up on the MVC pattern. If you want to do this in PHP, I believe [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org) provides a good way to do MVC in PHP. There is also a shopping-cart solution that is already written in PHP called [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/). It is open source so you can take a look under the hood to see how they do things. For Ruby there is [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), and the Groovy language has [Grails](http://grails.org/). Java has a whole host of frameworks (Spring and JSF come to mind).

Comment: Hi Vivin,
 Thanks. I know CakePHP and Ruby on Rails well(worked on many projects ). Both are MVC, in fact CakePHP is shadow copy of ROR. So we don't need to think about MVC. Anyway i believe - best way to build such site using rails framework. I'm thinking about the multi store stuffs, i didn't do that before - how to manage this thing? Such as creating a store for signed up user while configuring with subdomain too?

Comment: Like I said, it's a very broad question that you're asking. But if you wanted to do multiple store-fronts, you're essentially looking at a multitenant solution. Depending on the framework, there are different ways to handle the subdomains. I believe Grails has a multitenant plugin.